# Send Binary Image Data Over WebSockets In C++

Tags: c++, image, websocket

I am looking to send image data in binary format from a [C++ WebSockets server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371188/A-Cplusplus-Websocket-server-for-realtime-interact) to the browser and then have the browser to interpret the data to display the image to the end user.

Here is my C++ code to read image and send data -

```
WebsocketClient& client = (WebsocketClient&) (*pClient);
WebsocketDataMessage response(EchoCommunication);

FILE *img = fopen("test_image.png", "rb");
fseek(img, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long filesize = ftell(img);
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);
rewind(img);    

while (!feof(img)) {
    fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), img);
    response.SetArguments(buffer);
}
client.PushPacket(&response);
```

In Chrome Network tab I am able to see binary frames being received but having no luck in displaying image in browser. I have doubts if data being sent is valid.

[image]

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Also, `sizeof(buffer)` is `sizeof(char*)`, i.e. most likely either 4 or 8.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right, its 4. Could that be an issue?